# `import pandas` in Rmarkdown: works in the console, but doesn't knit

Tags: python, r, pandas, r-markdown, reticulate

I'm trying to write Python code in an Rmarkdown file in RStudio. Generally speaking it works fine. I can write code chunks and knit them perfectly. I can also import and use packages: anything using, say, `numpy` or `math` runs and knits well.

Despite being able to run and knit code chunks that use other packages, I can't seem to knit the file when it contains chunks that use `pandas`. I can run these chunks and obtain the expected output. A minimal example would be simply:

```
import pandas as pd
```

which returns the (expected) output:

```
Python 3.9.4 (/usr/local/bin/python3)
Reticulate 1.20.9000 REPL -- A Python interpreter in R.
```

(I can also run code chunks using `pandas` functions.)

The problem is that, when I knit, I get the error:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' Detailed traceback: File "<string>", line 1, in <module> File "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 44, in _import_hook level=level Calls: <Anonymous> ... py_capture_output -> force -> <Anonymous> -> py_call_impl Execution halted
```

I don't understand why I am able to *run* these code chunks, but not *knit* them.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your Rmarkdown file look somewhat similar to this for a simple example?

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "User"
date: "5/6/2021"
output: html_document
---

    
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(reticulate)
```
    
```{python}
import pandas as pd
iris = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv')
iris
```
````

And you still get error? sometimes you may need to reinstall pip packages, usually `pip3 install pandas` works, you can also add `py_install("pandas")` inside your r chunk under `library(reticulate)` to have it install pandas to help it render properly. Sometimes making simple examples help break the problem down into smaller chunks

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel! Running `py_install("pandas")` solved the issue. I had already installed the package using pip3, so it is not quite clear to me why this was necessary... (Also, it doesn't seem to be necessary for me to load `library(reticulate)` in my  Rmarkdown file at all. It knits fine without it.)